# Как изменить значения объекта?

Tags: javascript, объекты

У меня такой вопрос: есть объект, и я хочу изменить его значения, например, преобразовать их в нижний регистр.
Я написал код, но мне кажется он слишком объемный:

```js
let car = {
    mark: 'Pontiac',
    model: 'GTO Judge',
    year: '1969',
    color: 'black',
    origin: 'USA'
}
console.log(car);

let arr = Object.entries(car).flat();

let val = []
let keys = []
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (i % 2 != 0) {
        val.push(arr[i])
    } else {
        keys.push(arr[i])
    }
}

let low = val.toString().toLowerCase().split(',');

let new_arr = [];

for (let j = 0; j < keys.length; j++) {
    new_arr.push([keys[j], low[j]])
}

let new_car = Object.fromEntries(new_arr)
console.log(new_car);
```

Есть ли более короткое и изящное решение подобной задачи?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы как будто задались целью пойти самым сложным путём) Кажется, достаточно так:

```js
let car = {
    mark: 'Pontiac',
    model: 'GTO Judge',
    year: '1969',
    color: 'black',
    origin: 'USA'
};

for (const key of Object.keys(car)) {
  car[key] = car[key].toLowerCase();
}

console.log(car);
```

Или так, если вам покажется читабельнее:

```js
let car = {
    mark: 'Pontiac',
    model: 'GTO Judge',
    year: '1969',
    color: 'black',
    origin: 'USA'
};

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(car)) {
  car[key] = value.toLowerCase();
}

console.log(car);
```

Если же нужно создать копию, можно так:

```js
let car = {
    mark: 'Pontiac',
    model: 'GTO Judge',
    year: '1969',
    color: 'black',
    origin: 'USA'
};

let new_car = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(car).map(([key, value]) => [key, value.toLowerCase()])
);

console.log(new_car);
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное! А насчёт сложного пути, то это как будто "по иронии судьбы" - этот путь был на тот момент для меня наиболее понятен. :)

Comment: @AntAnt Думаю, вы не зря по нему ходили, разведанные маршруты наверняка пригодятся для более подходящих к ним задач)